# React Native Testing network images for a 404

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am using the Image component to show an image from the web.

**Problem :**

> If the image does not exist on the web, I would like to use a default
>   image. There is a defaultImage option but isn't supported on android.
>
> Is there a solution for both android and ios?
>
> *I would like to avoid having to send another HTTP/HTTPS request to
>    test for a 404.*

Answer (score 4):

There is an onError prop on the  tag that you could use to Handle '404'.

For exemple using the state:

```
    <Image
      source={this.state.thumbnail}
      onError={(e) => {
        console.log(e.nativeEvent.error);
        this.setState({thumbnail: thumbnailDefaultImage});
        }
      }
    />
```

See here for the different props : http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#onError